# How to print frequent input in text area in java script?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

I have two textareas in jsp page the values entered in first textarea value should be displayed in next text area frequently using jQuery.

Here is the code I've tried so far

```
function getMsg() 
{ 
    document.getElementById("chatBox").value =
        document.getElementById("messageBox").v‌​alue;

    document.getElementById("messageBox").value=""; }' 
}
```

Comment: `OnBlur` event of first textarea set value of next textarea using javascript.

Comment: You have to show that you at least attempted to solve this problem by yourself. At least provide us with the code you wrote and we will attempt to help you.

Comment: @NFE i cant understand your point. my process is chat application if i entered the text in first text area it should cleared and it should enter the next area.

Comment: 'function getMsg()
                                {
                                   
                                    document.getElementById("chatBox").value=document.getElementById("messageBox").value;
                                    document.getElementById("messageBox").value="";
                                }'

Answer (score 0):

In jquery you can try the following

```
$("#textAreaOne").keyup(function() {
    $("#textAreaTwo").val($("#textAreaOne").val());
});
```

**Update:**

It sounds from your comment that you want to append text to the second text area, you would have to create a button that the user will click to fire your event

Create a button, for example

```
<button id="chatButton">Chat</button>
```

Then wire the buttons onclick event to perform the append functionality, for example

```
$("#chatButton").click(function() {
    $("#textAreaTwo").val($("#textAreaTwo").val() + "\n\n" + $("textAreaOne").val());
});
```

Comment: actually am getting the values from first one to second but if i enter the data once again in first text area and submit the older value in the text area 2 is resets

Comment: Hi @Suresh, sorry I do not understand exactly what you are trying to do? Can you perhaps explain more?

Comment: Do you ant to keep the old text in textarea 2 and just append?

Comment: Updated my answer, I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Is this you were expecting

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#firsttext_area').keyup(function () { 
    $("#sectext_area").val( $('#firsttext_area').val());
  });
});
```

## **[Demo in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vinishanto/g3KcL/)**

Comment: am using javascript and servlet. am not familiar with jQuery

Comment: This is just implemented by JQuery and javascript what you asked for.
 You can even write the code you specified above inside the function, but not advisible. you need to write $("#textAreaTwo").val($("#textAreaOne").val() as ser65439 said

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {                                       
    $("#test1").keyup(function() {                  
        $('#test2').val(this.value);                  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the exact answer for my question. I tried with this and it is working.

```
    <script>
    var tempMsg;
    function getValue()
    {
        var userMsg="Me: "+document.getElementById("messageBox").value;
        var chatMsg=document.getElementById("chatBox");
        tempMsg=chatMsg.innerHTML+=userMsg+"\n\n";
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can implement this by event `onChange`.